# Are causative verbs transitive or intrasitive?

Tags: verbs, passive-voice

Question 1:
I have had **my hair** *cut*.
Here is 'my hair' an object or a complement?

Question 2:
Are causatives **transitive** or **intrasitive** verb?

Question 3: what is passive causative?

Comment: Hello Salim, and welcome to ELL! On this site, we can only ask one question at a time. While all of your questions are connected to a single topic --causatives-- , if you really want the answer to all of them, you need to write three separate questions. You can start by using the [edit] button to reduce this to one question only. You should also tell us what you already know about the topic so we don't waste time telling you things you already know. Thanks! When you've done that, please reply to this comment with "@gotube" and I'll open the question again.

Answer (score 1):

I can't fully explain what the syntax is, but I can say that "my hair" is an object of some kind in that sentence. An object is often defined as a type of [complement](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9995/), so I would say it also a complement.

"Cut" here is the past participle (or passive participle) of the transitive verb *cut*: it may be clearer to use a different verb as an example (e.g. "I have had my hair **trimmed**"). Thus, this is a kind of passive clause:

> Many passives don't have ***be*** [...] The other verbs that sometimes accompany passive clauses include ***come, get, go, have, hear, make, need, see,*** and a few others (though there are all sorts of limitations on the constructions that different verbs require). Here are a few examples [...]
>
> Mary got arrested at the demonstration yesterday.
>
> Try not to get your private life discussed by the newspapers.
>
> I saw him attacked by a flock of birds.
>
> I had this made for me by a carpenter.
>
> Susan had her car stolen out of her driveway last week.

("[The passive in English](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922)", *Language Log,* January 24, 2011, Geoffrey K. Pullum)

Comment: Many many thanks for your comment...

Answer (score 1):

> I have had my hair cut.

An object needs to be either a noun phrase or a determiner phrase.  Here *my hair* is a noun phrase and is hence the object of the verb *had*.

ecampusontario says

> If a Verb head takes a complement that is some category other than an NP or DP, then that complement phrase does not count as a direct object.

[ifioque](https://www.ifioque.com/parts-of-speech/verbs/causative-verb-forms) explains the causative structures.

> Causative verbs are structured into two forms:
> Active Causative Form (Done by Somebody/Something)
> Passive Causative Form (Done to Somebody/Something)

> The **passive causative** structure is preferably used in the following cases:

> When the person who does something is obvious

> When it is not necessarily important to mention the person who does something

> When we don’t know the person who does something

Using the causative verb **have**, the **passive causative** sentence is of the form

> Subject + C.V “Have” + Object (person/thing) + **Past Participle** of Verb + [“By” + “Agent” (person/thing)]

as in your example.

The **active causative** form is

> Subject + C.V. “Have” + Agent (person/thing) + Verb’s **Base Form** + Object (person/thing)

> I have him take my photograph.

As shown above, both forms have an object.  Causative verbs are hence transitive.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much...